# Change a series I have been given

Tags: python-2.7

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, Float, DateTime,           ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, reconstructor

from app import utils
import datetime
import pandas

from base import Base
from series import Series


class ConstantSeries(Series):
__tablename__ = 'constantseries'

# ID Primary Key (linked to parent) 
id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('series.id'), primary_key=True)

# The value of this series to be returned for all periods.
value = Column(Float)

__mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'constantseries'}

def GetData(self, scenario, periods):
    """Get data values for the specified periods.
    """
    return pandas.Series(data=[self.value]*len(periods), index=periods)
```

I have been given the code above but I want to be able to change it so that I can have a series that has different values depending on what day it is. For example if it is a weekday I have a value of 100 and for a weekend have a value of 200

Comment: I still want to keep the same output format

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me how you are calling the above code and what it currently returns?

It seems that the  GetData function just returns a data structure,  i.e. it returns the structure of a  Column for every period, but no actual data. 
What's not shown here is how the actual data in the Columns is populated and accessed.

You could loop through your periods and build the Series data according to the day e.g if periods contained ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']

```
def GetData(self, scenario, periods):
    mydata = {}
    for p in periods:
        if p in ['sat','sun']:
            e[p] = 200
        else:
            e[p] = 100

    return pandas.Series(mydata, index=periods)
```

Then calling GetData should return something like 
'mon'    100
'tue'    100
...
'sat'    200
'sun'    200

but thats not the structure you want and i dont think its how the Getdata function is being used.

Comment: cap = (ConstantSeries(value=1647))# 2574*0.64
def GetData(self, scenario, periods):
    rtn = {}
    for timest, val  in cap.GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).iteritems(): 
        if timest.weekday_name in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:
            rtn.append(0.72 * val) #0.46*2574
    else:
            rtn.append(1.0 * val)
        
cap2 = [rtn]

Comment: I then add in the line. (i need it to be in this format)

cap2.GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).plot()

Comment: <ipython-input-95-dea1985e61aa> in <module>()
----> 1 cap2.GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).plot()
      2 #cap2.plot()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   2670             if name in self._info_axis:
   2671                 return self[name]
-> 2672             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2673 
   2674     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'GetData'

Comment: I could be missing something but it seems the first time cap2 appears is when you do  cap2 = [rtn]   which means cap2 is just a basic list.    Then you do cap2.GetData  but i don't think it has that function since its a basic list.

Comment: what seems strange is that they refer to Series instead of list, perhaps the Pandas library has overwritten the basic list constructor to build a Series instead.  Anyway,  i don't think List  or Series have the GetData method,  only  ConstantSeries

Comment: perhaps modify  the outer GetData so that it returns [rtn]   e.g.

Comment: def GetData(self, scenario, periods): 
        rtn = {}
        for timest, val in cap.GetData(base_scenario,utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).iteritems():
        if timest.weekday_name in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:rtn.append(0.72 * val) 
  #0.46*2574 
  else: rtn.append(1.0 * val) 
  
  cap2 = [rtn]

Comment: ffs every time i press enter it adds the comment

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-366-3c126c15f9fb> in <module>()
      6 for timest, val in cap.GetData(base_scenario,utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).iteritems():
      7     if timest.weekday_name in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:
----> 8         rtn.append(0.72 * val) #0.46*2574
      9     else:
     10         rtn.append(1.0 * val)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: This is the error I get with this: Series was defined with getdata added into it, just like constant series. I am just defining cap2, it shouldn't really be a basic list but more like ConstantSeries, which has the attribute Getdata. This issue is ConstantSeries/Series don't have the attribute 'append' and hence I can't change them the way stated above. Is there any other way you know of that I can add in append to ConstantSeries? or any other way you can think of

Comment: Hi sorry I ballsed up on that code, mixed up lists and dictionaries.  Lists ([..]) have .append  whereas dicts ({...}) don't.    I've edited it now so it shouldn't give that error.

Comment: It's all got a bit confusing, especially with the way this forum displays the comments.    Can you send me the procedure / class from start to finish.  And use indents to make it display as code.   Then i'll be able to see clearer what you're trying to do.    Because  the last piece of code you sent me, it's not clear if that's inside a class, or standalone.     procedure etc.   Sounds like you want to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetData(self, scenario, periods): 
    rtn = {}
    for timest, val in cap.GetData(base_scenario,utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).iteritems():
        if timest.weekday_name in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']:
            rtn[timest.weekday_name] = (0.72 * val) 
            #0.46*2574 
        else:
            rtn[timest.weekday_name] = (1.0 * val) 
    return [rtn]
```

Comment: actualy i think you can remove the "self" argument,   and then you just do   GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).plot()

Answer (score 0):

```
#Define ConstantSeries class
#I have made no changes here, just what you already had
class ConstantSeries(Series):
    __tablename__ = 'constantseries'

    # ID Primary Key (linked to parent) 
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('series.id'), primary_key=True)

    # The value of this series to be returned for all periods.
    value = Column(Float)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'constantseries'}

    def GetData(self, scenario, periods):
        """Get data values for the specified periods.
        """
        return pandas.Series(data=[self.value]*len(periods), index=periods) 
#End of class definition


#Define new special Cap2Series class
class Cap2Series(Series):
    #I'm not sure how tablename is used so be aware, might need to put constantseries as before
    __tablename__ = 'cap2series'

    # ID Primary Key (linked to parent) 
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('series.id'), primary_key=True)

    # The value of this series to be returned for all periods.
    value = Column(Float)

    #Same as above, I'm not sure how this is used so be aware,  might need to put constantseries as before
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'cap2series'}


    #Define GetData method of our new special class
    def GetData(self, scenario, periods):

        #instantiate new ConstantSeries instance called cap when you call GetData
        cap = (ConstantSeries(value=self.value))

        rtn = {} 
        for timest, val in cap.GetData(scenario, periods).iteritems():
            if timest.weekday_name in ['Saturday', 'Sunday']: 
                rtn[timest.weekday_name] = (0.72 * val) 
                #0.46*2574              
            else: 
                rtn[timest.weekday_name] = (1.0 * val)            
        return pandas.Series(data=rtn, index=periods)
#End of class definition


#Instantiate new Cap2Series instance called cap2
cap2 = Cap2Series(1647)

#Call GetData method of cap2 instance
cap2.GetData(base_scenario, utils.enumerate_periods(start,end,'H','CET')).plot()


#Is this something like what you're trying to do?
```

Comment: That's what I want to do and I thinks it's almost correct. The problem is its states ConstantSeries is not iterable (As it has been properly defined not to be) I think there needs to be another definition of a series which can be changed (i.e not constant) but I could be talking rubbish...

Comment: I've tried swapping things round and stuff but essentially you get 2 problems. 1 is a simple list does not have the attribute getdata and the other is that a constantseries is not iterable. hence you can't get out of the trap by defining one or the other. if that makes sense?

Comment: Hmmm that's strange,  does it say which line gives the non-iterable error?   I can't see where we are iterating ConstantSeries at any point.  We call  .iteritems()  on the output of the GetData method of a ConstantSeries but the output of that method is a regular Series.    Do we need to use ConstantSeries at all?    Note that a lot of this stuff is using specific libraries (such as Pandas) that I've never seen before,  so the whole idea of Series is new to me.